# How to get the length of cycles in a Cycles[] expression?

Tags: permutation

I am looking for a way to get `{5,2}` for a `Cycles` object, like: `Cycles[{{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7}}]`. This could help with conjugacy classes.

The function should give back the length of the cycles the permutation consists of, in the natural ordering of the cycles as defined by Mathematica (e.g. `Cycles[{{6,7},{1,2,3,4,5}}]` would still have a "shape" of `{5,2}`).

Comment: Are you looking for something like `Length /@ First @ Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7}}]`? (It could be useful to apply a `Sort` to the result as well, I'm not sure) As a function definition: `cycleShape[Cycles[x_List]] := Sort[Length /@ x]`

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please be explicit about what you want to achieve. Don't just give an example and let people guess.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I added a clarification.

Comment: @thorimur, yes, that's exactly I was looking for. Thank you for the help, if you add a response, I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: That is not what numpy's `shape` does ... The equivalent of `np.shape` is `Dimensions`.

Comment: You are completely right @Szabolcs, thank you. Removed the confusing reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for something like `Length /@ First @ Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7}}]`, we can easily package that in a function:

```
cycleShape[Cycles[x_List]] := Length /@ x
```

The question then is how you want the "shape" to be ordered; for example, should `Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7}}]` have shape `{5, 2}` or `{2, 5}`? If we want to put the shape into a canonical form based only on the list of cycle lengths we can just use `Sort`:

```
cycleShape[Cycles[x_List]] := Sort[Length /@ x]
```

But if we want it to reflect the canonical ordering of the cycles, we can simply use the original definition. This is because `Cycles` automatically sorts its argument (try evaluating `Cycles[{{6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}]` by itself). However, using the first definition (without `Sort` applied afterwards) would mean that, for example, `Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}]` and `Cycles[{{1, 2, 5}, {3, 4}}]` (both of which are in canonical Mathematica form) would have different shapes, despite being conjugate permutations (by the permutation `Cycles[{{1, 3}, {2, 4}}]`).

Answer (score 1):

```
shape = Apply[Map @ Length];

shape @ Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7}}]
```

> ```
> {5, 2}
> ```

```
shape @ Cycles[{{6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}]
```

> ```
> {5, 2}
> ```